# Function only outputs the last node but not the merged list + Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list

Here is my approach when merge two linked lists:

```
def merge(self, l1, l2):
 cur = Node() #Creating a dummy node

 while l1 and l2:
  if l1.val <= l2.val:
   cur.next = l1
   l1 = l1.next
  else:
   cur.next = l2
   l2 = l2.next

#Skipped a block here to keep it short, not related to the question

 return cur.next
```

But the function only returns the last node instead of merging, and when I add a pointer to it, it does the right thing:

```
def merge(self, l1, l2):
 cur = Node() #Creating a dummy node
 p = cur #Pointer

 while l1 and l2:
  if l1.val <= l2.val:
   p.next = l1
   l1 = l1.next
  else:
   p.next = l2
   l2 = l2.next

return cur.next
```

Can someone explain? I can't seem to understand the purpose of using a pointer here. Many thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, the second code is not completely correct. Your `p` has never been moved.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the `merge` is correct they extract elements till both of them are having elements what if either `l1` or `l2` finishes them remaining elements will be `unmerged`.

In the below approach we are just moving around `cur.next` when we return curr.next it will be the last Node since we are setting this vlaue only either through `cur.next = l1` or `cur.next = l2` because of this the below approach will get only last `Node`.

```
 while l1 and l2:
  if l1.val <= l2.val:
   cur.next = l1
   l1 = l1.next
  else:
   cur.next = l2
   l2 = l2.next

#Skipped a block here to keep it short, not related to the question

 return cur.next
```

## Merge:

```
def merge(l1, l2):
    start = None
    curr = None

    arr = list()
    
    while l1 or l2:
        if l1:
            arr.append(l1.val)
            l1 = l1.next
        elif l2:
            arr.append(l2.val)
            l2 = l2.next
    arr = sorted(arr)
    for val in arr:
        if curr:
            curr.next = Node(val = val)
            curr = curr.next
        else:
            curr = Node(val = val)
            start = curr
    return start
```

## Source:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val = None, nextN = None):
        self.next = nextN
        self.val = val 

def merge(l1, l2):
    start = None
    curr = None

    arr = list()

    while l1 or l2:
        if l1:
            arr.append(l1.val)
            l1 = l1.next
        elif l2:
            arr.append(l2.val)
            l2 = l2.next
    arr = sorted(arr)
    for val in arr:
        if curr:
            curr.next = Node(val = val)
            curr = curr.next
        else:
            curr = Node(val = val)
            start = curr
    return start 

def printLink(node):
    temp = node
    while temp!= None :
        print(temp.val, end = '-')
        temp = temp.next
    print()


node1 = Node(val = 1)
node1.next = Node(val = 3)
node2 = node1.next
node2.next = Node(val = 4)


node2 = Node(val = 1)
node2.next = Node(val = 3)
node3 = node2.next
node3.next = Node(val = 8)
node3.next.next = Node(val = 5)

printLink(node1)
printLink(node2)

printLink(merge(node1, node2))
```

Comment: Using a list `arr` is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with both code snippets, is that in the loop you attach the node (either `l1` or `l2`) to the same `next` attribute, over and over again. So each iteration overwrites the attribute value that was determined by the previous iteration.

In each iteration you need to *move* the reference to the next node -- the one that was just assigned to `next`.

The second snippet is slightly better, as it foresees that you need two references: one to remain at the dummy node, and the other one that walks forward as nodes are assigned to `next` attributes.

Some other remarks:

- Use more indentation. It is common practice to use 4 spaces for each indentation.
- Use descriptive variable names. If a node is a dummy node, why not *call* it `dummy`?

So:

```
def merge(self, l1, l2):
    dummy = Node()
    current = dummy
    
    while l1 and l2:
        if l1.val <= l2.val:
            current.next = l1
            l1 = l1.next
        else:
            current.next = l2
            l2 = l2.next
        current = current.next  # This was missing!

    # Attach the remainder (either l1 or l2)
    current.next = l1 or l2

    return dummy.next
```